# How do visiting foreign pilots access Duats or Duat?

Tags: weather

I'm visiting the US and will get my foreign licence verified, but this means that I won't have a US license or medical. I understand that it is a requirement to sign up for Duats and Duat?!

Any idea or suggestion on how else to use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just arrived back home after being in the US for some months. I was required to have a FAA class 3 medical, because I did some flight training there, and luckily the one I've received is also is a student pilot certificate with the number on it you require to register for DUAT. Some of my colleges didn't have this number and so they were not able to register until getting there FAA pilot certificate. This will be send to your home adress, most probably when you are home again. In the US you'll only get a temporary certificate (peace of paper). The only number you'll find on it is your current license number.

Now what you can try: One of my colleges simply wrote an e-mail to duats helpdesk where he described his situation, giving all the information they require on their registration page with his foreign license number and attached a photography of his license and a proof that he'll be in the us for the next months. Less than 24 hours later he had a log-in. We had a student Visa, but if you don't have something like this, just try it without it, or take a photography of something else looking trustworthy.

Good luck and enjoy your trip!

Edit: I was just looking for the e-mail address, but for any reason my browser refuses to load duats website. As far as I remember, you'll find it at the registration page. If someonewho can access the website likes to add the e-mail adress please feel free to do so, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks. I emailed DUATS my CASA licence and the letter I have received from the FAA. They got back to me and just need a US address and a US phone number. Will update the post if I get access.

Answer (score 6):

Falk is correct; you can contact the service providers directly, explain your situation and they should be able to provision an account without a US pilot's license or medical certificate.

DTC DUAT (duat.com) can be reached anytime at: 800-243-3828
CSC DUATS (duats.com) can be reached anytime at: 800-345-3828

As an alternative, may I recommend trying Lockheed Martin Flight Services' Pilot Portal at https://www.lmfsweb.afss.com.  They are the flight services contract provider for the FAA.  You can create an account by simply providing a valid email address.

It provides all of the same functionality as DUAT/DUATS, but Lockheed's briefing products are the exact same ones their telephone briefers use. Their website has a tool called "NextGen Briefing" that translates all of your briefing data into plain text, which makes reading your brief super fast and easy.  Of course, you can also read the coded text, if you're into that kind of thing (or you're training).

On the website, you can also create a pilot profile that is linked to your mobile number so when you call 800-WX-BRIEF to file a flight plan, their computers will prefill your aircraft data for you.

You can also file, ACTIVATE and CLOSE flight plans through the website.  Also, unlike DUAT(S), flight plans are immediately available to ATC/Flight Service when filed.